# Java, Spring как сделать фильтр на сайте по параметрам?

Tags: java, spring

Java, Spring как сделать фильтр на сайте по параметрам?

Пример:
Есть и-нет магазин, у товаров есть параметры (вес, размер, разрешение экрана, цвет и т.п.)
Пользователь на сайте выбирает нужные ему отборы и получает выдачу товаров.

Куда копать, что почитать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал с использованием Spring Data Specifications, работает отлично
Инфу черпал по ссылкам ниже

https://overcoder.net/q/422962/java-spring-rest-api-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2

https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/

https://reflectoring.io/spring-data-specifications/